# Blender 3.1[.2] on Windows 10: every run says "trying to install non-verified app"

Tags: windows

I downloaded the latest Blender (3.1.2) as a ZIP and unzipped it, because I want to execute it alongside other Blender versions that I have installed.

*Every time* I try to execute blender.exe I get an annoying Windows popup: "The app you're trying to install isn't a Microsoft-verified app..." If I select "Install anyway" it runs.

- I'm not trying to *install* anything. Why doesn't Windows know this? (I guess I'll need to ask Microsoft too.)
- Reconfiguring Windows to "install from anywhere" is a terrible workaround, and not really a solution at all.
- Does anyone else see this? Does anyone have an explanation / workaround / solution?
  Thanks.

Comment: Where did you download the zip from?  This should not happen with zips from blender.org.

Comment: I downloaded the "latest", as a zip, from blender.org.

Comment: I had done basically the same for 3.0, 3.0.1 - they didn't act this way. I got one popup warning, I said "install anyway", and never got nagged again.

Comment: tried blender.org:zip:3.1.1 - nok
tried blender.org:zip:3.1.0 - nok

Comment: sounds like there's a problem with Windows Defender, or whatever alternative anti-virus you're using, then.   Maybe try one of the Windows forums?

Comment: I tried Microsoft support - they kind of said "talk to Blender" :/ Odd that 3.0.x seem more normal, 3.1.x very different.

Comment: I gave up and changed the Windows preference to "Install from anywhere". The Settings:Apps combo box "Choose source of apps" was missing from Settings for a normal user (I think it used to be there). The combo box only appears for Administrator (now). Actual source of the changed behavior is still unknown.

Comment: Giving up for now. Re-downloaded and retested 3.0.x, 3.1.x and they all behave the same (warning never goes away). So most likely a Windows issue. Windows Defender is a good guess - since blender.exe isn't an installer, seems like a Defender bug. Or maybe something tightened down.